# reorder columns in a tensor according to a dictionary

Tags: python, pytorch

I don't know how to explain it correctly, so the title might be misleading.
What I want to do is to move columns from a 3d tensor *t1* to another 3d tensor *t2* according to the indices. There's a dictionary *td*, and a *(k,v)* pair in *td* means that *kth* column of *t1* will be the *vth* column of *t2*

Currently, I'm doing it this way:

```
for k,v in td.items():
    t2[:,:,v] = torch.select(t1, 2, k)
```

but yes, it's super slow, as there are millions of them.
What would be the best way to do the work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming no repeated values then you can use

```py
t2[:,:,list(td.values())] = t1[:,:,list(td.keys())]
```

Comment: Thanks! but it says it only takes int as index.
First, it says it cannot accept dict_keys as index, 
so I tried converting them to lists / tensors but to no avail

Comment: Answer of @jodag worked with me without any problems.

Comment: @obtuseFox can you update your question with a test case where this fails? It should work provided the information you gave.

Comment: Okay, I'm actually trying this on the output from the huggingface language model. I'll try with a more bare example and see if it works

Comment: Thought I tried it properly but guess I did something wrong. Now it works like a charm. It still takes some time, but got 10 times faster. Thanks a million!